# Show JSON in tableview IOS Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

Dear fellow programmers.
I have to connect to an api and use the json I get back to store it in a table.
Using AFnetworking, Xcode and ios.
So far it has been taing me a full day and drives me insane. I've tried several tutorials and projects but I just can't get it to work.

The first problem is I cant seem to find my key in the json that I get back..

Of course I have to parse the json, which does not really work for me either

Can you please help me get my json into a table view?

The api I use is : https://api.9292.nl/0.1/locations?lang=nl-NL&q=amsterd

The json I recieve in the app as output is 
{

```
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": "station-amsterdam-centraal",
      "type": "station",
      "stationId": "asd",
      "stationType": "Station",
      "name": "Amsterdam Centraal",
      "place": {
        "name": "Amsterdam",
        "regionCode": "NH",
        "regionName": "Noord-Holland",
        "showRegion": false,
        "countryCode": "NL",
        "countryName": "Nederland",
        "showCountry": false
      },
      "latLong": {
        "lat": 52.378706,
        "long": 4.900489
      },
      "urls": {
        "nl-NL": "/station-amsterdam-centraal",
        "en-GB": "/en/station-amsterdam-centraal"
      }
```

etc

```
The code I have right now is:
//
//  ViewController.m
//  9292apiconnection
//
//  Created by TheDutchBeast on 02-09-14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Lambregts. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *posts;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *post;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"http://api.9292.nl/0.1/locations?lang=nl-NL&q=amsterd" parameters:nil success:^(
       AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Please help me define the key from the json code and how to get these values into a table in Xcode , ios
. Only ID and NAME needs to be shown in the table

Please no links to tutorials, since I have seen them all
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this convert the response json into `NSDictionary`

```
NSDictionary *receivedDataDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

now access the values which you want by using key names , like

```
NSString * id = [receivedDataDic valueForKey:@"id"];
NSString * name = [receivedDataDic valueForKey:@"name"];
```

use those variables where you want

make these changes in your code

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
  NSString * id ,* name;
} 

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *posts;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *post;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"http://api.9292.nl/0.1/locations?lang=nl-NL&q=amsterd" parameters:nil success:^(
       AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

         NSDictionary *receivedDataDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];

         id = [receivedDataDic valueForKey:@"id"];
         name = [receivedDataDic valueForKey:@"name"];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using AFNetworking, the response object is an NSDictionary Object, there is no need to convert to an NSDictionary

you should be able to parse the locations array like this.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager =
  [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:@"http://api.9292.nl/0.1/locations?lang=nl-NL&q=amsterd"
    parameters:nil
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
      NSArray *locations = [responseObject objectForKey:@"locations"];
      for (id obj in locations) {
        NSLog(@"id: %@, name: %@", [obj objectForKey:@"id"],
              [obj objectForKey:@"name"]);
      }
  }
  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,
            NSError *error) { NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); }];
```